# How to type special characters (@) using send_keys in watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to type an simple e-mail in a text field in a website using cucumber/ruby/water-webdriver. But the "@" symbol does not appear. For example, I write:

```
$browser.send_keys "testemail@gmail.com"
```

in the textfield, it appears: testemailgmail.com.

I tried using `[:shift, "'"]` and it also does not work.

Also tried:

```
$browser.text_field(:id => "search-global").set "testemail@gmail.com"
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: That's pretty weird.  I'd suspect there's something specific to the site-under-test because--if the `@` character wasn't allowed by `watir-webdriver`--then logging into an site would be impossible.  Can you provide the HTML that reproduces this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working normally now. I read somewhere this was something to do with chromedriver. Updated and it's fine.
Thanks for the help.